# Python enum34 access by name

Tags: python, python-2.7, enums, backport

I am using the Enum backport [enum34](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/enum34) with Python 2.7.

According to the documentation it should be possible to access enum members by their name, using item access.  That is, the following should work:

```
from enum import Enum

class Foo(Enum):
    bar = 1
    baz = 2

print(Foo['bar'])
```

However, when I run the code I get this error in the last line:

> TypeError: 'type' object has no attribute '`__getitem__`'

Am I missing something here or is this functionallity just not implemented in the 2.7 backport?

Comment: Works for me (both Python 2 and Python 3).

Comment: @vaultah: I just tested it in a new, virgin virtualenv where I only installed enum34 and there it worked. So maybe there is a conflict with some other package? Any idea how I can trace this?

Comment: What does `import enum; print(enum.__file__)` tell you is imported? You perhaps have a different module installed elsewhere. Then compare that file with the new virtualenv `lib/python2.7/site-packages/enum/` package contents to see if you have an old version.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yepp, it was indeed using a different module. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You might be getting a conflict with the Enum module. Try this:

> pip uninstall Enum

With both `Enum` and `Enum34` installed, this did not work. After uninstalling `Enum`, it worked like a charm.